# Yii2 Allow access to only specific controllers and restrict access to other controller

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-user

I have a yii2 advanced project with many controllers, I want only some controllers to be accessible by users and block access to other controllers.
Using access control I can set rules for actions but not controllers, any suggestion please

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few type of configurations:

1) Block access to whole app (ak backend) with main config:

```
// ../config/main.php
return [
    // ...
    'components' => [
         // ...
    ],
    'as access' => [
        'class' => yii\filters\AccessControl::class,
        'except' => ['site/error', 'site/login', 'site/logout'],
        'rules' => [
            ['allow' => true, 'roles' => ['@']],
        ],
    ],
];
```

2) Block access to specific controllers by extending an abstract controller class

```
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use yii\web\Controller;

/**
 *  AbstractSecured controller
 */
abstract class AbstractSecuredController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::class,
                // ...
                // rules
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

Now you can extend this controller in your controllers

```
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;

/**
 * MyNonPublic controller
 */
class MyNonPublicController extends AbstractSecuredController
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return ArrayHelper::merge(
            parent::behaviors(),
            [
                // ...
                // controller specific behaviors
                // you can even rewrite access behavior config
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

3) You can also config ACL

Comment: Thanks a lot, the second approach works for me, really appreciate your response Sir